# gruntjs: how to move a file out of the way

Tags: gruntjs

I need to move a file out of the way before one of my Grunt tasks run, and then put it back after the task has completed.

How do I do this with GruntJS?

Basically I want to run this command:

```
# move node-webkit out of the way
mv app/node-webkit ./tmp

# run grunt task

# move node-webkit back
mv ./tmp/node-webkit ./app/
```

Comment: Probably be better to exclude the file from the operation in question. Maybe you could expand (with Gruntfile code) on what exactly you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, have a look at [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell). In your init config:

```
shell: {
    move: {
        command: 'mv app/node-webkit ./tmp'
    },
    moveback: {
        command: 'mv ./tmp/node-webkit ./app/'
    }
}
```

Then, register a function that runs the move command before the other tasks you want to run, then run the moveback task.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    'use strict';
    grunt.registerTask('mytask', [
        'shell:move',
        'othertaskshere',
        'shell:moveback'
    ]);
};
```

Comment: I guess there's no way to use `grunt-contrib-copy` to move files? If not, this looks good.

Comment: Copy will only copy files :-) There's `grunt-rename` (https://github.com/jdavis/grunt-rename) if you'd prefer to use a plugin to abstract the `mv` command, personally I prefer the shell task as it's more succinct.